# Сделать net/http.HandleFunc по маске/регекспу?

Tags: golang

Можно ли заставить net.http.HandleFunc сравнивать строку по маске/регекспу, например, когда требуется использовать URL типа /foo/[0-9]/bar или есть другие более правильные решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прекрасная библиотека http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux в которой все это уже имеется. Ну, а если сильно хочется написать велосипед, ее исходники открыты и просты.